# "Alarms and reminders" permission in "not allowed" status (impossible to change to "allowed")

Tags: android

Good afternoon:

I have a Galaxy A32 smartphone and I am having a very strange problem.

I am using my phone with a work profile and I am installing an application in this profile that requires the "Alarms and reminders" permission to be set to "allowed" in order to work properly. This permission appears in Android 12 and by default, after installing the application, it should appear as "allowed" (Google states the following: "The type of this permission is "Special app access". You can find it on Settings > Apps > Special app access > Alarms & reminders. This permission is already granted at install-time. In order to revoke it, the user needs to manually go to this screen."). When I am outside the work profile (in the private profile) and I install the application, this permission appears as "allowed", but in the work profile it appears as "not allowed" and cannot be enabled in any way (you enable it, go back and it still appears as "not allowed").

The funny thing is that if I restart the phone and go back to the indicated permission, it appears as "allowed" and you can enable/disable it without any problem. This seems to be a full-blown Samsung bug and I would like you to tell me what I should do to avoid having to restart the phone, something that would be very uncomfortable for users of this application.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards.